# Beginner coder: would like to give overall photo a dim and highlight when it's hovered

Tags: html, css

would like to give overall photo a dim and highlight when it's hovered. any help appreciated! img is inside a flexbox div with clickable link.

```
.box {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: flex-start;
}

.box img {
position: relative;
flex: 1 1 80%;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
vertical-align: bottom;
border: 5px solid var(--light-blue);
transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.65);
}

.box img a {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use brightness filter to make it dim.

```
.box img:hover {
   filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

you can reduce 90% for making it dimmer and increase it to make it less dim.